# How to collect 2 one to many relationships to create one running total?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

From the diagram that I have above I need to sum the amount instock to I need
[image: Relationships]

- Sum of amount sold for the certain bike
- Sum of amount produced for the certain bike

Then to store the total in "InStock"

I have tried to create queries but none of them seem to work as I want. Please could someone help me out? This should be fairly simple!

Comment: Is there some major reason why you don't have a stock table?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson You mean work everything out in that table? Could you suggest how?

Comment: Depends on your UI. But Bike Info would be a parts table. Then Stock would be BikeID and Quantity. When you record production or sales in your UI, you increase or decrease Quantity for the relevant BikeID. It means you are writing an Application though, not just a database.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a stock table
BikeInfo is a Part
Production and Sales only have an impact in terms of they add and remove stock.

As would say scrap, or stock reconciliation, or provisioning, marking a bike as sold so you don't sell it again, or not bother making anymore because you have plenty "in stock"

Ask yourself this question how are you going to record a return. You could have BikesReturned table. Now your Stock is Produced - Sold + Returned...
What's next a BikesWeCannotFindInStock table and a BikesWeDoNotKNowWhereThisCameFrom table
:)
Or you could Change TotalSold in BikesSold...

I've done a lot on this sort of system, you do not want to go down these routes, trust me.

PS you are going to have a similar problem trying to relate cost in bikeinfo to price sold at in bikesold. How much of one depends on whether cost is cost or  price or value. Three different numbers...

To get the current position in your schema, can't remember whether Access lets you do nested joins

Create a Query called say QProduction

```
Select BikeID,Sum(Built) as Produced From Production Group By BikeID
```

Another called qSales

```
Select BikeID, Sum(TotalSold) as Sold From BikesSold Group By BikeID
```

Then it's just a couple of outer joins say

```
Select b.BikeName,p.Produced, s.Sold (p.Produced - s.Sold) as [In Stock] 
From BikeInfo b
left join qProduction p On p.BikeID = b.ID
Left Join qSales s on s.BikeID = b.ID
```

Not tested, may be typo in there, but the idea is sound.

The huge problem with the design is if something went wrong in recording or production, you have no clue what your stock is and the only way to reconcile it would be to create a dummy production or sales record.

Edit for an update query

```
Select b.ID, (p.Produced - s.Sold) as [In Stock] 
From BikeInfo b
left join qProduction p On p.BikeID = b.ID
Left Join qSales s on s.BikeID = b.ID
```

and call it qInStock

then

```
Update BikeInfo b
Set b.InStock = q.[In Stock]
inner join qInStock q On q.ID = b.ID
```

Should do the job

Damn complicated this, bet you wish you had a stock table.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense but where do I put the last statement you put? I have never used joins before!

Comment: I have tried to insert what you wrote and change it however I am getting no where, I understand that you must join the table and then minus them from eachother. Is the result then InStock in the bikes table?

However what are the joins for? To then join them on the certain IDs to do with the bikes?

Comment: The joins deal with the likely scenario of producing bikes but not having sold any yet, and the all too likely unfortunate circumstance of having sold some even though you never produced them. What change were you trying to make?

Comment: To correct the syntax! Also having problems on where do we put the code, into a query? Or a macro? Cant get either to work!

Comment: That was how to get the answer, Are you saying you want an update query to set inStock in BikeInfo?

Comment: I donk't do access, but somewhere in it, you used to be able to do "SQL View". So you create a query switch to SQL View and then paste it in. Never did figure out the GUI myself, can't stand the things.

Comment: Yeah this is what I have been trying to do and I want to give up! I wanted to make it in access because of time thinking it was simple! And I shouldnt need to as it is for a small part of a Uni project! thanks for the help!